# Как построить мультифрагментное взаимодействие с активити

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, android-interface

Имеется активити с 2 фрагментами посредством FragmentManager.
В теле активити инициализирован public List.
Необходимо передать данные из фрагментов в этот List.

Нашел в документации два способа: Interface и bundle.
Что применять и с чем возникнет меньше подводных камней? Например:
Формируя в первом фрагменте интерфейс и применяя его к активити имеем следующее:

```
MainActivity implements FragmentOneInterface {
```

В то же время, если нужно подключить обработчик со второго активити, то получается:

```
MainActivity implements FragmentOneInterface, FragmentTwoInterface {
```

Как быть?

Comment: Если данные однотипные, то почему бы не использовать один и тот же интерфейс во всех фрагментах?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как реализовать, чтобы доступ к интерфейсу был из обоих фрагментов?

Comment: Например скастовав `getActivity()` во фрагменте к интерфейсу, который реализован в активити.

Comment: Вариант. Сделайте базовый фрагмент, который в конструкторе принимает этот List и сохраняет, наследуйте все фрагменты от него и делайте с List'ом что хотите